# is it possible to add parameter validations to path variables in a dotnetcore api app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

given the method:

```cs
/// <param name="containername">The container the file resides in.</param>
/// <param name="fileName">The name of the file to get.</param>
/// <returns>The file specified.</returns>
[HttpGet("{containername}/contentfiles/{fileName}", Name = "Get")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(FileResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ErrorResponse), StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable)]
public ActionResult Get(string containername, string fileName)
```

I check that the containername and fileName are valid for my purposes, and then get the data.

Swagger automatically gives me **required*, but not the min length and max length, which makes sense because it has no idea where to find those.

I hoped I could do something like:

```cs
/// <param name="containername" minimum="3" maximum="63">The container the file resides in.</param>
```

but it just drops those. How can I add them to my autogenerated Swagger docs (I am using Swashbuckle, in case that matters)?

Comment: If you are using .NET Core 2.1 or higher you can use the ApiController attribute on your controller.... Then you can just use the normal validation attributes available in MVC

Comment: I am using 3.1. but the parameters are different on each endpoint -- and the documentation I am wanting to add is obviously dependent on the end point. But I am not using full on MVC, this is just a web api endpoint. what are these "normal validation rules" you are talking about? Do you mean attributes that you specify on models that are used for payloads? How could I do that on path parameters?

Comment: If you use ApiController attribute on your Controllers.... You can leverage the full MVC validation but on Api.... That is one of the things that attribute does.  Yes I am talking about model validation through attributes like you do on full mvc... You see when you apply the [ApiController] on a api controller you enable these validations.  How to do it with parameters? I would start by creating models that contain my parameters.

Comment: could you provide a link that illustrates the validations applied to path parameters please?

Comment: Take a lookt at my answer. It is a complete sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an example project using ASP.NET Core 3.1 Api project.

First lets look at the controller and notice the ApiController attribute and also notice the FromRoute attribute:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace ValidationExampleApi.Controllers
    {
      [ApiController]
      [Route("[controller]")]
      public class ValidationController : ControllerBase
      {
        [HttpGet("{containername}/contentfiles/{fileName}")]
        public bool Get([FromRoute]RequestModel request)//it will return 400 bad request if validation fails
        {
          if(ModelState.IsValid)//please note in this case this line will never be hit.
          {
            return false;
          }
          else
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }

    }
```

Now let's look at the model and notice the data annotations with some validation specifications:

```
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace ValidationExampleApi.Controllers
    { 
      public class RequestModel
      {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string containername { get; set; }

        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [StringLength(5, MinimumLength = 2)]
        public string fileName { get; set; }
      }
    }
```

Now lets look at my startup class and notice I added vanilla default swashbuckle configuration:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

namespace ValidationExampleApi
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddControllers();
      services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
      {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
      });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if(env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
      app.UseSwagger();

      // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
      // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
      app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
      {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
      });

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Now look at my swagger how it shows I am violating the MaxLength:

[image]

**Final notes:**

You can also combine Route Parameters with Query Parameters.
You can also apply the "FromRoute" attribute at the property level in your model.
There are many ways to do this. This is just a "get you started" example.

**Customizing the error response:**

Here you can see how to use an Error Handler and also InvalidModelStateFactory and ValidationProblemDetails: [Handle Errors Custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Here is another example on how to use InvalidModelStateFactory:
[Another example on how to customize error](https://coderethinked.com/customizing-automatic-http-400-error-response-in-asp-net-core-web-apis/)

Comment: as a folllowup question, how can I modify the response body?

Comment: thank you for taking the time do do this, very kind

Comment: I will update my answer with two links where it shows how to customize the error response.

Comment: @robertotomás I have added 2 links that show everything about customizing error messages in ASP.NET Core Api.  The first one is from Microsoft and shows a few ways to achieve this.